# discord bot command import text from text file

Tags: python, command, discord

I want to implement the feature in my Discord Bot by command to sent upon command. The information/updates in the changelog are on a .txt file in the same folder.
How do I get that text inside the file to be sent?

Comment: Are python's built in file I/O tools (`open()`) not working? Can you share the relevant bits of the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example code i think thats what you mean

```
client = commands.Bot('!')

@client.command
async def command(ctx):
    open_file_ = open('file.txt', 'r')
    await ctx.send(open_file_.read())
```

is this what you want?

Comment: do you know how i can run this file (ghost.vbs) with the same command

Comment: no sorry,  idk how to run a vbs file through python. if you know the code just add it to the command and it should run the file

Comment: os.system("xxxxx.vbs")
        f = open("tytytyt.txt", "r")
        time.sleep(0.05)
        file = f.read()
        array = file.split('\n')
        await ctx.send (file)